Problem with cycling through Styles to change NextParagraphStyle - Run time error 91 - Word vba
Problem with cycling through Styles to change NextParagraphStyle - Run time error 91 - Word vba
EDIT: Tim Williams spotted the problem. I was not using Set for an object variable.
My macro is:
Sub StyleFollowingBodyText()
    ' Charles Kenyon 15 December 2024
    ' Set the following style for most QuickStyle paragraph styles to be Body Text
    Dim StyleCount As Long
    Dim thisStyle As Style
    Dim iCount As Long
    '
    With ActiveDocument
        Let StyleCount = .Styles.Count
        For iCount = 1 To StyleCount
            Let thisStyle = .Styles(iCount)
            If thisStyle.QuickStyle = True Then
                If thisStyle.Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Or wdStyleTypeLinked Then
                    If thisStyle.NameLocal <> "Normal" Then
                        thisStyle.NextParagraphStyle = "Body Text"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next iCount
    End With
End Sub

and I get this error message when running it:

This error message seems to be somewhat of a "catch-all" and is not that helpful. As pointed out by Tim Williams, the problem is not using the Set command for an object variable.
It is stopping on Let thisStyle = .Styles(iCount).
The purpose of the macro is to change most of the paragraph QuickStyles to have the Body Text style as the following style. I am trying to change more than 50 [Quick] Style Sets because I prefer to not have the bulk of my documents using the Normal style.

Objects use Set for assignment, not Let

For example:
Sub StyleFollowingBodyText()
Dim s As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For s = 1 To .Styles.Count
    With .Styles(s)
      If .QuickStyle = True Then
        If .NameLocal <> "Normal" Then
          If .Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Or .Type = wdStyleTypeLinked Then .NextParagraphStyle = "Body Text"
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub


Correct and updated. Thanks for spotting that!

Thanks........!

I tried discarding the problem statement and not assigning a variable to the style and it works.
I simply used .Styles(iCount) instead of the variable StyleCount.
Sub StyleFollowingBodyText2()
    ' Charles Kenyon 15 December 2024
    ' Set the following style for most QuickStyle paragraph styles to be Body Text
    Dim StyleCount As Long
    Dim thisStyle As Style
    Dim iCount As Long
    '
    With ActiveDocument
        Let StyleCount = .Styles.Count
        For iCount = 1 To StyleCount
'            Let thisStyle = .Styles(iCount)
            If .Styles(iCount).QuickStyle = True Then
                If .Styles(iCount).Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Or wdStyleTypeLinked Then
                    If .Styles(iCount).NameLocal <> "Normal" Then
                        .Styles(iCount).NextParagraphStyle = "Body Text"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next iCount
    End With
End Sub

Tim Williams' comment to my question is spot-on as to why I was getting the error. I was using "Let" rather than "Set" for an object variable.
I also found the following macro by Jay Freedman dealing with the Normal template's styles.

Sub StylesToBodyText()
    ' Jay Freedman 2023-12-18
    ' Change next style to Body Text, Based on style to Body Text in Normal
    ' You can use the macro below to change all of the "based on Normal" and "following paragraph Normal" styles
    '    in the Normal.dotm template to be based on and followed by Body Text.
    ' Before you run the macro, save a copy of the Normal.dotm template in some folder other
    '    than the Templates folder, as a backup in case something goes wrong.
    ' I deliberately did not include a Save in the macro,
    '    as you should examine the results in the Styles pane before you manually save and close the Normal.dotm window.
    '    If anything is amiss, close the window without saving and see where the problem occurred.
    ' https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-change-the-style-for-following-paragraph/64644dfc-92a7-44b7-baa8-53fe622344b8
    '
    Dim sty As Style
    NormalTemplate.OpenAsDocument ' Comment this line out to apply active document or template and not normal template
    For Each sty In ActiveDocument.Styles
        If sty.Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Then
            If sty.BaseStyle = "Normal" Then
                sty.BaseStyle = "Body Text"
            End If
'
            If sty.NextParagraphStyle = "Normal" Then
                sty.NextParagraphStyle = "Body Text"
            End If
        End If
    Next sty
    '   After checking styles, save and close normal template
End Sub


I will probably be adopting that structure but thought it could help others here as well. He is using the For...Each structure rather than the count.
